# Saving entity in new document via current ID

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I will give my best to explain situation.

I have HTML that provide me a random element from document.

I achieved that like this:

This is service:

```
@Override
public AdventureHolidays findRandomAdventureHolidays(String type) {
    if (elementsToReturn.size() == 0) {
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("typeOfAdventureHolidays").is(type));
        List<AdventureHolidays> newData = mongoTemplate.find(query, AdventureHolidays.class);
        Collections.shuffle(newData);
        elementsToReturn.addAll(newData);
    }
    return elementsToReturn.poll();
}
```

And this is contorller:

```
@GetMapping("/getRandomSummerCamps")
public String getRandomSummerCamps(Model model) {
    countSummerCamps.incrementAndGet();
    if (getCountSummerCamps() <= adventureHolidaysService.countAdventureHolidays("summerCamps")) {
        model.addAttribute("randomSummerCamps", adventureHolidaysService.findRandomAdventureHolidays("summerCamps"));
        System.out.println("in if");
        return "randomSummerCamps";
    } else {
        countSummerCamps.set(0);
        return "noMoreDoc";
    }
}
```

So when I call that controller, I can see that element on chrome since I added a HTML for that. That works fine. Now, I want to add a save button which will actually save a current element in new document `savedDocByUser`

That looks something like this:

```
 [{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "634d1c7e773e58610892b4dc"
  },
  "loggedUserId": "admin",
  "adventureHolidaysList": [
    {
      "$ref": "adventureholidays",
      "$id": {
        "$oid": "62c9b5bf797b12f8c9a867ca"
      }
    }
  ],
  "_class": "demo.tripadvisorapp.userProfile.model.UserProfile"
}]
```

As you can see I have a list below `loggerUserId` which hold ID of element from another entity,

I tried to create a button for that like this:

```
@PostMapping("/savedAdventureHolidays/{postId}/post")
public UserProfile saveElement(@PathVariable(value = "postId") String postId,
                                 @Valid @RequestBody UserProfile comment, Model model) {

    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String username = authentication.getName();

    return adventureHolidaysRepository.findById(postId).map(post -> {
        comment.setAdventureHolidaysList(Collections.singletonList(post));
        comment.setLoggedUserId(username);
        model.addAttribute("comment", comment);
        return userProfileRepository.save(comment);
    }).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("PostId " + postId + " not found"));
}
```

and that works also fine when I test it in postman and when I know ID of element that I want to save.

I mean, this is how I post it in postman `http://localhost:8080/api/userProfile/savedAdventureHolidays/62c9b5bf797b12f8c9a867ca/post`

and that works fine when I set ID of AdventureHoliday id manually.

Problem is when I try to create a controller for button which will do this stuff automatically on chrome page.

On HTML side I added this:

```
 <form role="form" th:action="@{/api/userProfile/savedAdventureHolidays} + '/'+ ${postIds} + '/post'"
      th:method="post">
    <button id="login" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

But when I hit that button I got this NULL for postId in URL

`http://localhost:8080/api/userProfile/savedAdventureHolidays/null/post`

So I think my main problem is getting current ID from element that is provided on HTML page.

I have this app on Heroku, use admin123 for password and admin for username, then you click on adventure holidays > summer camps, you'll get one random element from document, so for example on that page I have `save doc` button and I want to as explain before to create a feature, so after user click on `save doc` save current element that is provided in new document. Basically I want to create a `bookmark` button or `save for later` something on that way.

Heroku link: https://trip-advisor-app.herokuapp.com/api/auth/loginAndRegisterForm

Comment: Have you figured this out? I think there's a problem on how you set or where you get teh `postIds`. As you see in the link you've posted that the `postIds` is null. You haven't included this part in you question so it's kinda hard to debug. If you say the saving works if you run it from postaman then this seems to be the issue, how you populate that id